# Is a UNION ALL the correct way to fetch this data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.3 database with a users and an affiliates table.

**users table columns**

```
+----+-------+
|    |       |
+----+-------+
| id | email |
+----+-------+
```

**affiliates columns**

```
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+
| id | referred_user_id | referrer_user_id | amount |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+
```

I tried the following query:

```
select
  users.email as referred_email,
  affiliates.amount
from affiliates
  JOIN users ON affiliates.referred_user_id = users.id

UNION ALL

select
  users.email as referrer_email,
  users.id
from affiliates
  JOIN users ON affiliates.referrer_user_id = users.id
```

It produces table with columns:

```
+----------------+--------+
| referred_email | amount |
+----------------+--------+
```

But I want a one to one table such as:

```
+----------------+----------------+--------+
| referrer_email | referred_email | amount |
+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

where I'm essentially substituting each  `*_user_id` with a `referrer_email` and a `referred_email` and then tacking on the corresponding `amount`.  What can I do differently?  I thought `UNION ALL` joined all the columns together.

Comment: `union (all)`  matches columns by their sequence in the `SELECT` clause. It discards the names you give to columns in the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought UNION ALL joined all the columns together.

No, `UNION ALL` concatenates the rows.  If you want to *join* columns you need to use a `JOIN`.

That might look like so:

```
select
  rer.email as referrer_email,
  red.email as referred_email,
  affiliates.amount
from affiliates
  JOIN users rer ON affiliates.referrer_user_id = rer.id
  JOIN users red ON affiliates.referred_user_id = red.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
select u1.referred_email as email1, u2.referrer_email as email2, a.amount
from affiliates as a, users as u1, users as u2
where a.referred_user_id = u1.id
and a.referrer_user_id = u2.id
```